# How can I wrap a table view in javafx when its size is more than my screen's size?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have a table view whose size is more than my screen size.
To view that table I have 2 solutions 
1-I have to provide a scrollbar by which user can scroll to the end of the table
2-Or warp the table when it meet the end of the screen.
First solution-I don't want to provide any scroll bar as I want user to view the table at one shot. so I want to wrap the table.

I searched and came to know that I could warp table header but I could'nt  find any hack to wrap the whole table. Any help on this will be great help for me

Comment: Have you tried to set maxWidth and maxHeight of table view ?

Comment: @shreyas yes i have tried with max width but instead of wrapping the table  a scroll bar is coming.